# Can't get video header to fit screen size?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to create a video header but whatever I try it seems to either overfill, and cause the screen to scroll horizontally because its original size quite big (I am using a small monitor), or it shrinks down to a small size or disappears.

Also my text and buttons get pushed off to the side even though the video has a z-index lower than the rest of the elements. I can't seem to get the video to adjust to the screen. I've managed to do it for the original banner image I had but can't for the video for some reason.

HTML:

```
    <!-- Header -->
<header id="top" class="header">
       <div class="videoCont">
        <video id="rndmVid" autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="http://convio.cancer.ca/mUFE/2016/one/videos/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
       </div>
        <div class="text-vertical-center">
            <h1>Event Title</h1>
            <h3>Tag Line</h3>
            <br>
            <a href="#about" class="btn-dark btn-lg">Learn More</a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

//log-in html code

</header>
```

CSS:

```
video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;

}

.header {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://convio.cancer.ca/mUFE/2016/one/img/cliffside.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;

}


.header h1 {
    font-size: 6.5em;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(0,0,0);
}

.header h3{
    font-size: 4em;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

For the purpose of showing you the comparison between the banner image and the video I've left the banner image uploaded. As you can see here:[test page](http://convio.cancer.ca/site/PageServer?pagename=%2FUFE_ON_Custom_Multi_2016) the text gets pushed off by the video (even when I set the video to `z-index: -9999;`), also you'll notice the image doesn't cause the page to scroll it works great. I can't seem to replicate this for the video.

I've gone through 3-4 related threads here on stackoverflow trying to figure out a solution but no luck. Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest restructuring your css a little bit, but let me know if this isn't what you're wanting:

```css
video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.videoCont {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-vertical-center {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

I've moved the z-index out of the video styles to start with, this is better applied to the div which it is sitting in.
The videoCont div I've set to absolute positioning, with it's width at 100% and the z-index as 1.
Then the text-vertical-center div is positioned above it - also using position:absolute, however with a higher z-index.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWWOOB

Edit: I actually use a service at times called coverr.co for setting up full screen hero videos. They have a great snippet at the base of their site which has a block of HTML, CSS and Jquery that makes it quite easy to set these up. It also handles fallbacks for old browsers and a jpg fallback.

http://www.coverr.co/

Their code looks like this:

```js
//jQuery is required to run this code
$( document ).ready(function() {

    scaleVideoContainer();

    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
    initBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        scaleVideoContainer();
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .poster img');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container .filter');
        scaleBannerVideoSize('.video-container video');
    });

});

function scaleVideoContainer() {

    var height = $(window).height() + 5;
    var unitHeight = parseInt(height) + 'px';
    $('.homepage-hero-module').css('height',unitHeight);

}

function initBannerVideoSize(element){

    $(element).each(function(){
        $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
        $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    });

    scaleBannerVideoSize(element);

}

function scaleBannerVideoSize(element){

    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
    windowHeight = $(window).height() + 5,
    videoWidth,
    videoHeight;

    console.log(windowHeight);

    $(element).each(function(){
        var videoAspectRatio = $(this).data('height')/$(this).data('width');

        $(this).width(windowWidth);

        if(windowWidth < 1000){
            videoHeight = windowHeight;
            videoWidth = videoHeight / videoAspectRatio;
            $(this).css({'margin-top' : 0, 'margin-left' : -(videoWidth - windowWidth) / 2 + 'px'});

            $(this).width(videoWidth).height(videoHeight);
        }

        $('.homepage-hero-module .video-container video').addClass('fadeIn animated');

    });
}
```

```css
.homepage-hero-module {
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    position: relative;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
    display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
    display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
}
.video-container .poster img {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.video-container .filter {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width: 100%;
}
.video-container video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage-hero-module">
    <div class="video-container">
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
            <source src="PATH_TO_MP4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
            <source src="PATH_TO_WEBM" type="video/webm" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
        </video>
        <div class="poster hidden">
            <img src="PATH_TO_JPEG" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: woah thanks so much Aaron! this is fantastic, not only did you fix my issue you also provided me with an excellent resource for hero videos. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately it gave me the same results as I've had before, where it causes the page to scroll horizontally. However you got it to fit right just before the "About the Event" which is awesome I may be able to use this for another project! thanks.

Comment: yep, well you can always set overflow-x: hidden to the main body, to remove the horizontal scroll